# FHIR media types

Tags: hl7-fhir

The spec and the C# reference library seem to different regarding the media types for fhir.

I would think that they should be:

- application/fhir+xml
- application/atom+xml
- application/fhir+json

What's the official answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct value has changed. The specification used to say "application/fhir+json" and "application/fhir+xml", but we changed it, after ballot, to "application/json+fhir" or "application/xml+fhir".

The reference implementations and servers still haven't caught up to this change. They will in the next few weeks.

The correct mime types are:

- `application/xml+fhir` - xml resource
- `application/atom+xml` - xml resource bundle
- `application/json+fhir` - json resource or resource bundle

Comment: Note, Atom (`application/atom+xml`) is no longer used and there is an explicit Bundle resource

Answer (score 1):

In addition, application/xml+fhir and application/json+fhir are also used when returning lists of Tags for the tag operations